# Reload div and set events in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I try to load a div via jQuery and I want to set a click-event on a dynamically created element that makes a request to a php-script and then reloads the div.
Unfortunately the Events aren't set after the reload.
My Code so far looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#incomplete").load("incompleteTasks.php", '', function () {
            //Setting Click-Events
            $(".btn_aufg").click(function () {
            window.alert($(this).attr("id"));
            var encoded = encodeURIComponent($(this).attr("id"));
            //Marking Task as completed...
            $(this).load("taskworker.php?action=complete&id=" + encoded);
            //reloading div
            $("incomplete").load("incompleteTasks.php");
    });
});
```

});

How can I activate the Event again after the user has clicked on a button?

Comment: You should create [delegated events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this...

```
 $(document).("click",".btn_aufg",function () {
    var encoded = encodeURIComponent($(this).attr("id"));
    $(this).load("taskworker.php?action=complete&id=" + encoded);
    //reloading div
    $("#incomplete").load("incompleteTasks.php");
 });

 $("#incomplete").load("incompleteTasks.php");
```

Comment: Thanks, but it should be $(document).on("click",".btn_aufg",function () instead of $(document).("click",".btn_aufg",function () {

Answer (score 1):

Use `on` instead

```
$("body").on("click", ".btn_aufg", function () {
  //Click function
});
```